# I want to add fragment button but it is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile, android-button

i am new to android, i want to add fragment button like in activity, but i can't add it where do i add it (findViewById is not coming out when i try to add it anywhere)

````
    private ImageView walleticon;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    public static SatisFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SatisFragment fragment = new SatisFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_satis, container, false);
    }
    public SatisFragment(){

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

In fragments the view is accessed in a different way.

In an Activity you use, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` This allows the use of straight calls to `findViewById(R.id.button);`

In a Fragment `findViewById` only exists at the individual view level.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_satis, container, false);
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button); //<-- Here is your button
    return view;
}
```

Comment: the program crashes

Comment: kicks it out of the app

Comment: What does? Need more information than that.

Comment: normally the application works up to the part I made myself, but when I add the code you wrote, the program crashes when it comes to that fragment.